# Flutter, How to align text below the another container in when overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to show second text at below of container if Overflow, I am using row to display

```
        Row(children: [
            Text("test test"),
            Container(height: 50, width: 50, color: Colors.red),
            Text("test test test test test test test")
          ])
```

Problem :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpVf1.png

Expected : [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSfVA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your `Container` in a `Flexible` to let your `Row` know that it's ok for the `Container` to be narrower than its intrinsic width. `Expanded` will also work.

```
Flexible(
  child: Container(
.....
```

Comment: Problem : Test Test "Container" Test Test Test......

Expected :

Test Test "Container" Test Test Test //overflowed text get below

Test Test

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, children: [                                       
  Text("test test"),                                                                                 
  Stack(                                                                                             
    children: [                                                                                      
      Container(height: 50, child: Center(child: Text("test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1"))),
      Container(height: 50, width: 50, color: Colors.red),                                           
    ],                                                                                               
  ),
```

It looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use a `TextSpan` for what you want, like

```
Text.rich(TextSpan(children: [
      const TextSpan(text: "test test"),
      WidgetSpan(child: Container(height: 50, width: 50, color: Colors.red)),
      const TextSpan(text: "test test test test test test test")
    ]))
```